# taking a gcloud snapshot of a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Given a postgres database on a Google cloud virtual machine instance, are we guaranteed snapshot consistency if we call pg_start_backup(), sync(), then take a snapshot of the instance?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

The documentation says this is true in "most situations", but I'm not sure how to determine what conditions would cause inconsistencies.